# Colorising a Sprite with a Texture Doesn't Work

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to make game sprites flash a colour when they are damaged with the colour quickly fading back to normal. All the sprites have bitmapped textures but they are not affected by the command. I tried the same on a SpriteNode with a plain coloured background and it does work, but the colour fades *in* not out:

```
//defines sprite
let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myTexture")
//defines action to colourise sprite over half a second
 let tintSprite = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1, duration: 0.5)
mySprite.runAction(tintSprite)
```

Nothing seems to happen and I assume this action doesn't work on textures. testing it on a simple sprite with no texture works but fades in over the duration:

```
 let test = SKSpriteNode.init(color: SKColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(80, 80))
        test.position.x = 100
        test.position.y = 200
        let tintTest = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1, duration: 5)
        test.runAction(tintTest)
        self.addChild(test)
```

This works fine but fades up from the original black to red over 2 seconds.

Does anyone know how to:
1. Tint textured sprites
2. set a colour instantly then make it fade back to normal.

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks.
Kw

Comment: in the first example... you don't have `self.addChild(mySprite)` before the SKAction...

Comment: more... in the answer, please

Comment: It's not that. I can see sprites on screen but they don't respond to the colorize action if they have textures.

Comment: I've done more testing and you're right - it does work for simple SKSpriteNodes even if they have textures. Unfortunately my sprites are a sub subclass of SKSpriteNode which seems to be interfering with this ability. I would have assumed that subclasses inherit the abilities of SKSpriteNode but perhaps the action only affects textures that are direct children of the SKSpriteNode.

Comment: What color is your texture?

Comment: shades of grey ranging from white to black, so it would definitely show up if it was working.

Comment: Does it work if you replace "myTexture" image with the default "Spaceship"? I tested your code and it worked as expected with Xcode 8/Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

The first "method" it's working if you add `self.addChild(mySprite)`

```
//defines sprite
let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myTexture")
self.addChild(mySprite) // missing
//defines action to colourise sprite over half a second
 let tintSprite = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1, duration: 0.5)
mySprite.runAction(tintSprite)
```

To fade it back:

```
let tintSpriteBack = SKAction.colorizeWithColorBlendFactor(0, duration: 0.5)
mySprite.runAction(tintSpriteBack)
```

**For SWIFT 3**

```
let tintSprite = SKAction.colorize(with: SKColor.red, colorBlendFactor: 1, duration: 0.5)
mySprite.run(tintSprite)
```

and

```
let tintSpriteBack = SKAction.colorize(withColorBlendFactor: 0, duration: 0.5)
mySprite?.run(tintSpriteBack)
```